# node.js+mongodb cant link database(error in console)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to figure out how it works using this guide - https://medium.freecodecamp.org/building-a-simple-node-js-api-in-under-30-minutes-a07ea9e390d2

But something went wrong ...

**server.js**

```
const express        = require('express');
const MongoClient    = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const bodyParser     = require('body-parser');
const db             = require('./config/db');
const app            = express();
const port = 8000;
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
MongoClient.connect(db.url, (err, database) => {
  if (err) return console.log(err)
  require('./app/routes')(app, database);
  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('We are live on ' + port);
  })
})
```

**note_routes.js**

```
module.exports = function(app, db) {
  app.post('/notes', (req, res) => {
    const note = { text: req.body.body, title: req.body.title };
    db.collection('notes').insert(note, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        res.send({ 'error': 'An error has occurred' });
      } else {
        res.send(result.ops[0]);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

**db.js**

```
module.exports = {
  url : "mongodb://<testuser>:<password1>@ds135881.mlab.com:47981/mydb"
};
```

Error in console - 
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdeI8.jpg)

Comment: The error message is pretty clear "username contains an illegal unescaped character"

Comment: Can you post your **dburl**?

Comment: @Jack url : mongodb://<testuser>:<password1>@ds135881.mlab.com:47981/mydb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to remove those symbols "<" and ">" on username and password

Your link `mongodb://<testuser>:<password1>@ds135881.mlab.com:47981/mydb` shoud look like this : `mongodb://testuser:password1@ds135881.mlab.com:47981/mydb`

Comment: Thank you for help)I even could not think that the problem was this....

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
mongoClient.connect("mongodb://myuser:pass@host:port/?ssl=true", { 
                    uri_decode_auth: true 
}, function (err, db) {
        db.close();
});
```

or latest version you have to use auth

```
mongoClient.connect("mongodb://host:port/?ssl=true", {
  auth: {
          user: 'username',
          password: 'p@ssword',
  }}, function (err, db) {
     db.close();
  });
```